# Long running PHP process randomly stops with message 'Killed'

Tags: php, command-line-interface, kill, kill-process

I have a PHP script I wrote that I am running, and it has ran all the way through before, but for some reason, it keeps stopping with a message of 'Killed' ...

It is my box, no one else is logged in

The script does not have the word 'Killed' in it anywhere

What is killing my script and why?

Comment: Log file entries?

Comment: Nada, php_errors.log is empty, going to browse around and see if there is anything somewhere else

Comment: yup yup, in messages, Apr 17 05:29:31 Centos-PHP56 kernel: php invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x280da, order=0, oom_adj=0, oom_score_adj=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the culprit was OOM-KILLER due to no-swap-left, evidence was left in /var/log/messages

```
Apr 17 05:29:31 Centos-PHP56 kernel: php invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x280da, order=0, oom_adj=0, oom_score_adj=0
```